# IntegerString output using Roman numerals

Tags: number-bases

I noticed a peculiar behavior of the `IntegerString` command that I would like to bring to the attention of the community. The code is as follows:

```
Clear[i]
Symbol@IntegerString[1, "Roman"]
t1 = Table[{Symbol@IntegerString[i, "Roman"], i}, {i, 10}]
t2 = Table[{Symbol@IntegerString[i, "RomanLower"], i}, {i, 10}]
```

[image]

Observation:

I thought that the use of `I` was in conflict with the imaginary number and was thus avoided on purpose. I tried to convert zero (which wasn't part of the Roman system) and it got converted to `N` or `n` depending on case. Any insights on that are welcome.

---

I have tried this code on the free cloud account as well as on my Mathematica 12.2.0 Win7-x64 platform with similar results. I can't find many tags for this post either. As always, your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The first problem can be explained by noting that the symbol "I" has a predefined meaning, namely Sqrt[-1]. I have no explanation for the second problem.

Comment: For the second, `i` is used as `Table` index

Comment: If I don't use 'Symbol' the outputs are kept as `String`. It is the conversion of zero to `N` that is strange as well as the inconsistency between the Roman cases, so I considered it best to highlight it.

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence of your comment @Syed. So isn't `Table[{ Symbol["i"], i}, {i, 1}]` resulting in `{{1, 1}}` expected?

Comment: @Kuba, @I.M. You are right. Using the index `k` instead of `i` works, generating `{i, 1}` for both `t1` and `t2` above. The first part is resolved. I should have thought more before posting.